# Where will the DSCOVR mission Falcon 9 2nd stage rocket body end up?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, falcon-9, solar-sail, upper-stage

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/8101/12102) to *Why would a mission to Sun-Earth L1 have an instantaneous launch window?* suggests that this was quite a delta-v-intensive launch. It left the F9 2nd stage in a very high 17 day orbit around the Earth. DSCOVR is now in a heliocentric orbit in resonance with Earth, otherwise known as a Halo orbit or in this case a Lissajous orbit around the Sun-Earth L1 point.

In [Why can't custom-made TLEs for the DSCOVR launch booster in orbit around Earth work with SDP4?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45064/12102) I estimate the period of the first stage rocket body to be about 17 days based on TLEs in links in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/35534/12102). That makes the semimajor axis roughly 280,000 km, which means it's subject to strong perturbations from the Sun and Moon. That linked answer also says:

> It is true that TLEs for 2015-007B = DSCOVR booster are not provided by Space-Track.  However,  that object (and others in high Earth orbits) are occasional annoyances for the astronomers looking for near-earth asteroids,  and they've imaged 2015-007B many times over the last four years.  From these data,  I've computed orbital elements and fitted TLEs :
>
> https://www.projectpluto.com/pluto/mpecs/pseudo.htm
>
> https://github.com/Bill-Gray/tles/

which means some precise sightings have occurred. However, spent rocket bodies are large, white and mostly hollow and light, so they are subject to significant photon pressure and other non-Newtonian forces. For more on that see

- [Did Rosetta improve on models of non-gravitational effects on comet 67P's orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18474/12102)
- [this answer to *How well can the orbits of Jupiter Trojans to be visited by Lucy be predicted?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32740/12102)
- [Why do they think WT1190F is low density?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214700/83380) in Physics SE

**Question:** Is it known or has it at least been hypothesized where the DSCOVR mission Falcon 9 2nd stage will end up? Will it escape to a heliocentric orbit, or eventually crash into the Moon, or does "where it stops, nobody knows" apply?

Comment: The first stage is in a heliocentric orbit with parameters essentially identical to Earth's, due to its location at the bottom of the Atlantic.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I've adjusted the language to be stage-agnostic; is 2015-007B (40391) the 2nd stage then?

Comment: The Falcon 9 first stage never gets further than ~600 km downrange, flightclub.io's simulation has DSCOVR's booster coming down at around 500 km (https://flightclub.io/result/2d?id=872bbcb0-61a9-4392-b3dd-2a0beaf95c56). The only part of a Falcon 9 that ever reaches orbit is the second stage (considering payload adapters to be part of the payload).

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff indeed! I've edited again, thanks.